# Underscore: remove all key/value pairs from an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

Is there a "smart" underscore way of removing all key/value pairs from an array of object?

e.g. I have following array:

```
var arr = [
        { q: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit.", c: false },
        { q: "Provident perferendis veniam similique!", c: false },
        { q: "Assumenda, commodi blanditiis deserunt?", c: true },
        { q: "Iusto, dolores ea iste.", c: false },
    ];
```

and I want to get the following:

```
var newArr = [
        { q: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit." },
        { q: "Provident perferendis veniam similique!" },
        { q: "Assumenda, commodi blanditiis deserunt?" },
        { q: "Iusto, dolores ea iste." },
    ];
```

I can get this working with the JS below, but not really happy with my solutions:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    delete arr[i].c;
};
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) and [`omit`](http://underscorejs.org/#omit) in conjunction to exclude specific properties, like this:

```
var newArr = _.map(arr, function(o) { return _.omit(o, 'c'); });
```

Or [`map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) and [`pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) to only include specific properties, like this:

```
var newArr = _.map(arr, function(o) { return _.pick(o, 'q'); });
```

Comment: Beat me to it! @User789 You can also use _.pick if you want the opposite effect: `var newArr = _.map(arr, function(o) { return _.pick(o, 'q'); });`

Comment: @User789, Also, if you just wanted an array, you can also use the pluck method: `var newArr = _.pluck(arr, 'q');`

Comment: @mister_rampage - if I knew all key names up from the `pluck` way would be perfect.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - do you think there is a performance different? I will be running this on mobile site.

Comment: @User789 I'm not sure, but I would guess that `pick` would be nominally faster than `omit`. It may also depend on the kind of data you're processing. However, if speed is a big concern, a plain old JS solution like the one you've already written is probably the way to go.

Comment: @User789 You may want to check out Lo-Dash.js or Lazy.js to compare the performance. Underscore will use the native map function from the browser on the mobile device. I think for loops will always outperform, but I'm not sure about that for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

For Omit

```
_.map(arr, _.partial(_.omit, _, 'c'));
```

For Pick

```
_.map(arr, _.partial(_.pick, _, 'q'));
```