# How to remove or hide a key-value pair of an array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a collection of objects in an array like this:

```
[
  {
    "NAME": "John Doe",
    "AGE": 25,
    "CITY": "New York",
    "COUNTRY": "USA",
    "GROUP_ID": 1,
    "ACTIVE": 1
  },
  {
    "NAME": "Peter Parker",
    "AGE": 44,
    "CITY": "Los Angeles",
    "COUNTRY": "USA",
    "GROUP_ID": 2,
    "ACTIVE": 1
  },...
]
```

In my view I only want to display Name, Age, City and Country. Well, my question is how can I remove `GROUP_ID` and `ACTIVE` in every object of my collection? I was looking for a solution and found `.slice()` but I don't know exactly whether is it the right one and how to use this javascript function for each object in an array.

EDIT:
For more clarification. My view is defined like below:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="cItems in ::contentItems track by $index">
   <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in cItems track by $index" flex="auto">
      {{ ::value }}
   </span>
   <md-divider></md-divider>
</md-list-item>
```

Comment: When you are iterating the objects in that array, simply display the properties you are interested in. Why do you want to remove it from the object all together?

Comment: @yBrodsky Could you give me a better solution to return the values without these to key-value pairs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22918613/underscore-remove-all-key-value-pairs-from-an-array-of-object

Comment: @yBrodsky there's no reason to throw a library at this simple of a problem.

Comment: i think it is more an angular question, how to display some properties and some not, and not how to delete the properties from the object.

Comment: Could be. @Yuro can you provide some clarification?

Comment: You can check my answer or this Stack Overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object. However, please check the comments of my answer, since I share the opinion with @NinaScholz that your question is not well asked and has nothing to do with AngularJS.

Comment: @TomePejoski It is especially important for the ngRepeat directive. I need to display a list table of values in my view. But when I do a GET request to the server I get 6 keys in every object (you can see it above). but for my view I only need the first 4 keys with values. Nina Scholz is right. It is an angular question.

Comment: @yuro, so executing my code before passing the data to the ngRepeat is not working?

Comment: [How to filter (key, value) with ng-repeat in AngularJs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14788652/215552)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following lines:

```
contentItems.forEach(function (entry) {
  delete entry['GROUP_ID'];
  delete entry['ACTIVE'];
});
```

Comment: @yuro By the way this has nothing to do with AngularJS. This is pure JavaScript code.

Comment: @yuro If you want to use AngularJS to hide those properties, just don't bind them to any HTML element.

Comment: @yuro prepare the data (remove the attributes) before passing it to the ngRepeat.

Comment: Ok wait. I will try your solution.

Comment: Thanks.. I guess this solution is good enough. Is it right, that the properties don't really removed from the array?

Comment: @yuro perfect. They will be really removed, so if you need them later in the code they will be gone.

Comment: @yuro you can also add an ng-if in your template with value "key !== 'GROUP_ID' || 'ACTIVE'". This will hide only those keys but won't remove them from the object.

Comment: @yuro, so instead of {{ ::value }} use <span ng-if="key !== ('GROUP_ID' || 'ACTIVE')">{{ ::value }}</span>

Comment: @yuro please accept my answer if this works for you. Cheers.

Comment: Great.. But I don't want any static code in the view.. because I use this view also for several other controllers :)

Comment: @yuro then prepare the data in the JavaScript code where you want to, but don't work with the original array. Use var arrayCopy = arrayOriginal.slice(); to copy the array.

Comment: I tried the ngIf and ngShow directives but they still show the values of these two keys :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is a variable named `array`:

```
for ( var i=0,l=array.length; i<l; i++ ) {
  delete array[i]['GROUP_ID'];
  delete array[i]['ACTIVE'];
}
```

if you're using ES6 you could also do:

```
for ( let item of array ) {
  delete item['GROUP_ID'];
  delete item['ACTIVE'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments there is no need to delete the keys. You can simple avoid displaying them.

Still if deleting is objective then use `delete` method

```
a.forEach(function(item){
delete(item['GROUP_ID']);
delete(item['ACTIVE'])
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/mdwvsmu2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove properties of an object by using `delete`. I've added an array of properties to delete but you could delete them directly.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "NAME": "John Doe",
    "AGE": 25,
    "CITY": "New York",
    "COUNTRY": "USA",
    "GROUP_ID": 1,
    "ACTIVE": 1
  },
  {
    "NAME": "Peter Parker",
    "AGE": 44,
    "CITY": "Los Angeles",
    "COUNTRY": "USA",
    "GROUP_ID": 2,
    "ACTIVE": 1
  }
];

var propertiesRemove = ['GROUP_ID', 'ACTIVE']

data.forEach(function(item){
  propertiesRemove.forEach(function(prop){
    delete item[prop];
  });
});

console.log(data);
```

If you don't want to change your data and it's just a display issue you could render only the properties you want.

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="cItems in ::contentItems track by $index">
   <span flex="auto">{{cItems.NAME}}</span>
   <span flex="auto">{{cItems.AGE}}</span>
   <span flex="auto">{{cItems.CITY}}</span>
   <span flex="auto">{{cItems.COUNTRY}}</span>
   <md-divider></md-divider>
</md-list-item>
```

Comment: I know the simple solution of setting the properties in the template. But I need a dynamic solution :).. I guess to use nested forEach()-function is not so good for the performance.

Comment: @yuro you can update your `ng-repeat` with `(key, value) in getUpdatedItem(cItems) track by $index"` where the `function getUpdatedItem` returns the item with the properties you want based on the initial element without changing anything. Is that something more aligned with what you want?

Comment: Ok... and how looks like the function or how works it?

Comment: Add it on your controller and it could be as simple as `getUpdatedItem(item) { return { NAME: item. NAME,  AGE: item.AGE,
    CITY: item.CITY,
    COUNTRY: item.COUNTRY } }`. Can update answer with it if you want

Comment: it is also good. But the problem is when I use this dynamically. I always need to define all necessary properties and that's tedious.

Comment: You can do it dynamically in 2 ways. Or indicating which properties you want to include or by indicating the ones you want to exclude. That's essencially the purpose of the array I've added in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually to display required information in angular we don't need to remove other elements from array in template we can go with limited information.

ANGULAR CODE

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
  {
    "NAME": "John Doe",
    "AGE": 25,
    "CITY": "New York",
    "COUNTRY": "USA",
    "GROUP_ID": 1,
    "ACTIVE": 1
  },
  {
    "NAME": "Peter Parker",
    "AGE": 44,
    "CITY": "Los Angeles",
    "COUNTRY": "USA",
    "GROUP_ID": 2,
    "ACTIVE": 1
  }
]
});
```

Angular Template

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul ng-repeat="record in records">
<li>{{record.NAME}}</li>
<li>{{record.AGE}}</li>
<li>{{record.COUNTRY}}</li>
</ul>
```

But as you are asking following procedure will answer your question.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $data = [
  {
    "NAME": "John Doe",
    "AGE": 25,
    "CITY": "New York",
    "COUNTRY": "USA",
    "GROUP_ID": 1,
    "ACTIVE": 1
  },
  {
    "NAME": "Peter Parker",
    "AGE": 44,
    "CITY": "Los Angeles",
    "COUNTRY": "USA",
    "GROUP_ID": 2,
    "ACTIVE": 1
  }
]; 
$scope.records = $data.map(function(item){
delete(item['GROUP_ID']);

delete(item['ACTIVE']);
return item; 
});
});
```